# Assign Pyspark window function the same uuid for each window

Tags: python, pyspark, window, uuid, group

I have a Pyspark dataframe as such:

```
data = [ {"master_record_id": "001-0073-683496",
         'dob': datetime.date(2000, 1, 1),
         "patient_ssn": "123456789",
         "dodid": "1234567891",
         "dqi_id":"123",
         "site_id":700},
        {"master_record_id": "001-0013-101321",
         'dob': datetime.date(2000, 1, 1),
         "patient_ssn": "123456789",
         "dodid": "1234567891",
         "dqi_id":"123",
         "site_id":701},
        {"master_record_id": "001-0046-2845712",
        'dob': datetime.date(1999, 2, 3),
         "patient_ssn": "987654321",
         "dodid": "0987654322",
         "dqi_id":None,
         "site_id":775},
        {"master_record_id": "001-0048-2845712",
        'dob': datetime.date(1999, 2, 3),
         "patient_ssn": "987654321",
         "dodid": "0987654322",
         "dqi_id":None,
         "site_id":775}] 

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
```

I want to be able to assign a uuid for records that share the same dodid,patient_ssn, and dob using a window function.

At the moment I have a working solution, but it does not scale to millions of records. I believe what is slowing it down is looping through clusters and creating several dataframes. Is there a way to assign a uuid directly in the Window function? My working but inefficient solution below:

```
# Filter out any recrods with null dob/patient_ssn/dodid
df = df.filter("dob is NOT NULL AND patient_ssn is NOT NULL AND dodid is NOT NULL")
# Create a cluster id based on dob/patient_ssn/dodid
window = Window.orderBy(["dob","patient_ssn","dodid"])
df = df.withColumn("cluster_id",lit(f.dense_rank().over(window)-1))
    
cluster_list = set(df.select("cluster_id").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())    
df_list = []
# Iterate throuh clusters assigning uuid to each cluster. Each cluster will now be a new dataframe
for cluster in cluster_list:
    temp = df.filter(col("cluster_id")==cluster)
    df_list.append(temp.withColumn("uuid",f.lit(str(uuid.uuid1()))))
# Union all dataframes from df_list     
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll,df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason to use Window function.
How about concatenating all three "key" columns and then running md5?

.withColumn('uuid',md5(concat('dodid','patient_ssn', 'dob' )))